# How to retrieve the first key from Gee.SortedMap in Vala?

Tags: vala, sortedmap, libgee

How do I retrieve the first key from Gee.SortedMap in Vala?
For example if I have

```
Gee.SortedMap<int, string> foo = new Gee.TreeMap<int, string> ();
```

I want to get the first key, i.e. the lowest int in foo.
In Java we have java.util.SortedMap.firstKey(). I cannot find an equivalent in Vala.

Answer (score 1):

The `SortedMap` has an [`ascending_keys`](https://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.SortedMap.ascending_keys.html) property that returns a `SortedSet`. Then you can get the [`first()`](https://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.SortedSet.first.html) item from the `SortedSet`:

```vala
void main () {
    Gee.SortedMap<int, string> foo = new Gee.TreeMap<int, string> ();
    foo.set(2, "two");
    foo.set(1, "one");
    foo.set(0, "zero");
    print(@"First sorted key: $(foo.ascending_keys.first())\n");
}
```